# Naive Line Search for Gradient Descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand the Line Search approach to Gradient Descent (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search). It seems that a naive implementation would

```
while (termination criteria not met)
    1) Compute gradient at a current location
    2) Move in that direction until the objective function begins to increase
    3) Set current location to the location before the "increase" in step 2
    4) GOTO 1
```

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: That's correct, except that in #2 you would move in the direction **opposite** to the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less ;-) If you knew the minimum (what you are looking for), you could move "until the objective function begins to increase". But you don't know the minimum, so you must try a "good enough" step length $\alpha_k$. There are several ways, for example you can look for a step length such that:

- the function decreases, i.e. $h(\alpha_k)=f(x_k+\alpha_k p_k)< f(x_k)$, and the reduction is proportional to both the step length and the directional derivative (*sufficient decrease* condition);
- the slope of $h$ at $a_k$, $h'(\alpha_k)$, is greater than the initial slope (*curvature* condition); the initial slope is negative, so:

  - if $h'(\alpha_k)$ is greater because it's positive, then you can expect that $f$ increases if you choose a step greater than $\alpha_k$;
  - if it is greater because still negative but lesser in absolute value, then $\alpha_k$ is a good step toward the minimum.

Comment: When I've implemented "line search" in the past I would typically choose a conservative learning rate and iteratively step in the opposite direction of the gradient (e.g., in a loop), evaluate the objective function at each step, and stop when the objective function increases (then back up one step). Next, I would recompute the gradient at this new location and start the process again. I realize this doesn't find the true minimum along the "line" direction, but it yields reasonable results and runs very quickly.

Comment: Numerical Recipes (nr.com) has a very good discussion of multivariate nonlinear optimization methods, beginning with a clear explanation of why and how gradient descent will fail, and moving on to methods to overcome its inherent limitations.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the link, I'll check it out. I'm aware that gradient descent has a lot of limitations and weaknesses. My motivation for this question was to confirm that my understanding of gradient descent and line search is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not really your question, but fyinfo,
[Stochastic gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), SGD,
is a form of gradient descent with no line search, no function values at all,
gradients only.
My non-expert explanation is that you may have either or both of

- func(): cheap or expensive, noisy or not
- gradient(): ditto

so there are *very* different methods if you have func() only -- Derivative-free optimization, DFO --
or huge, noisy ML problems with fast gradients -- SGD;
see
[SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)
and [SGDRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html)
in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) .
Even when you have both func() and gradient(), 
it's not at all clear how to tradeoff
for low total cost ~  Nfunc * Funccost + Ngrad * Gradcost.)

Fwiw, I've found gradient descent with simplest-possible line search,
take the best of `[.1 .5 1 2] * stepsize * gradient()`,
not bad.

Comment: @Josh,
SGD proper uses *only* $\nabla f$, not $f$.
That said, *if* you have a big expression graph for $f$,
as for neural nets, then
[Automatic_differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation)
is a fast way to compute $\nabla f$.
[Backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)
is I think a special case of auto-diff.

Comment: Denis - SGD needs a **forward pass** (for an input sample). How would you do that without computing $f$ ? You can't update parameter values on an SGD iteration if you haven't computed inputs and outputs throughout the network for the **current** parameter values and input sample at hand. If you **only** have ∇ how would you update parameters in the network? Moreover even computing ∇ (at a particular point) itself requires much knowledge of the current activations through the network.

Comment: @Josh, look at the update formula under [SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent): $w \gets w - \eta \, \nabla Q$ -- that's it: no "forward pass", no "network". By "SGD" you seem to mean "SGD in the context of neural nets", is that right ? but they're not the same.

Comment: Computing $\nabla Q \rvert_{x_0}$ on $x_0$ often requires the evaluation of much of $Q\rvert_{x_0}$. Moreover if you see [the example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Example) from your link, the gradient **across** weight dimensions reuses much of the **same** computation, so it's common to "cache" it with a forward pass, which is effectively an evaluation of Q. So sure, you are **not** required to compute Q, but it's **extremely useful** to do so in practice for complex functions (e.g. when SGD is useful) whether or not one thinks of them as "neural networks".